# Help with Riemann.Stieltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose that $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)d(\alpha(x))}=0$ for any $f$ monotonous function in $[a,b]$. Show that $\alpha$ must be a constant function.

I've already use integration by parts and we have $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)d(\alpha(x))}=f(b)\alpha(b)-f(a)\alpha(a)-\int_{a}^{b}{\alpha(x)d(f(x))}$ and, using the hypothesis we can write $\int_{a}^{b}{\alpha(x)d(f(x))}=f(b)\alpha(b)-f(a)\alpha(a)$, a friend told me that I can chosse any $c\in[a,b]$ and the function $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq c$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise, but I'm not pretty convinced if this is a valid proof. Anyone can give me another hint or another proof more general or explain why this is a valid proof?